# How to do DateTime.Parse correctly

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I have the following method:

```
    private DateTime GetDateTimeFromString(string dateTimeStr)
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(dateTimeStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Log($"Exception while parsing {dateTimeStr}: {ex.Message}.");

            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

When I run this in Visual Studio it works fine. But when it is deployed to Azure it fails. The error is:

> Exception while parsing 21/4/2019 11:6:56: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I stick **21/4/2019 11:6:56** in the debugger, it works. Bamboozled. Can someone help please?

Please note it fails on Azure (as Web App) with or without CultureInfo.

Also on Azure, my web.config is set to:

```
<globalization culture="" uiCulture="" />
```

Comment: Check the culture settings on the host machine.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, thanks for the reply. Its a web app. The above code fails with or without the cultuerinfo paramter.

Comment: I don't think `DateTime.Parse("21/4/2019 11:6:56", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` ever succeeds - are you sure you show code that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yes. That was exact copy and paste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) and set parse format.

```
DateTime dt;

DateTime.TryParseExact("21/4/2019 11:6:56",
                       "dd/M/yyyy hh:m:ss",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                        out dt);
```

There are two reasons I would use `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead of `DateTime.Parse`

1. `DateTime.TryParseExact` return `bool`, you can handle it instead handle `Exception`. if the input string isn't matched with the format and culture. it will return `false`.
2. Determine the `Culture` and datetime format be parameters.

like this.

```
DateTime dt;

if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeStr,
                       "dd/M/yyyy hh:m:ss",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                        out dt))
{
    _logger.Log($"Exception while parsing {dateTimeStr}");
    dt = DateTime.Now;
}

return dt;
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H7oa4l)

Comment: Thank you so much @D-shih. It worked. I think I tried the TryParseExact method but I don't know what I did wrong as I was getting error. Possibly I didn't use DateTimeStyles. Thanks now it is all good now.

Comment: @Stackedup No problem glad to help

Comment: Careful about the casing.  `hh` is a 12-hour clock.  `HH` is 24-hour.  Without having an am/pm meridiem indicator (`tt`) then a 12-hour clock is not useful, as you won't be able to tell the difference between 1 am and 1 pm.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string dateTimeStr = "2019-04-35";
    DateTime dateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeStr, out dateTime))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
    }
```